# Why does a multiselect fieldtype custom field result in a DB error

Tags: custom-fields, fieldtype, channel-fields, multiselect

I have created a custom fieldtype that uses a multiselect box. However when I save the entry in the CMS, the following error occurs

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `exp_channel_data` SET `channel_id` = '27', `field_id_108` = Array, `field_id_109`...
```

Any suggestions? I have checked the Multiselect fieldtype within EE and my code looks OK (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a multiselect element, you're posting an *array* of data when the entry is saved. But you can't simply insert an array into the database - you need to turn it into a string.

So in your fieldtype's `save()` method, you need to do something like:

```
return implode('|', $data);
```

Or:

```
return json_encode($data);
```

Then you need to turn your data back into an array in `replace_tag()` and `display_field()`.

```
$data = explode('|', $data);
```

Or:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
```